# Test if a java object is executing from a jar file?

Tags: java, jar

I want to run tests for a Java project that will be deployed in a .jar file. But I don't want to go through the trouble of building the complete jar file while I'm debugging.

The problem is that I want to read from files which will be present within the jar, but are located elsewhere before it is built. I would like to test whether the program being run is contained in a jar file and, if not, tell it to look elsewhere for the necessary files like this:

```
java.io.File dataFolder;

if (isRunningFromJar())
   dataFolder = ...
else
   dataFolder = ...
```

Can this be done?

I am running the class file directly while debugging the non-jar variant:

```
java -cp 'src/' com.path.Run
```

Comment: You should not do this. Otherwise you are only exercising test code and not the production code.

Comment: I'm just debugging. This is not production code.

Comment: It will be, and part of it won't have been tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, you can use Class.getResource().getProtocal(). Below is a working example:

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String protocol = Test.class.getResource("Test.class").getProtocol();
        if(Objects.equals(protocol, "jar")){
            System.out.println("running in jar");
        } else if(Objects.equals(protocol, "file")) {
            System.out.println("running in file");
        }
    }
}
```

Or, here is a workaround may achieve the same goal in an easier way.

You can pass in a JVM parameter in dev env, for instace, java -Dfolder=

In the code,

```
if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(System.getParameter("folder")) //dev env
     dataFolder = System.getParameter("folder")
else
     dataFolder = <relative path in jar>
```

Depending on how serious the program is, you may want to remove the System.getParameter code before release.